# Getting keystroke from batch file

Tags: c, batch-file, keyboard, getchar

I am trying to achieve the following

I have a C program whose basic layout is as below and Press any key to continue is not starting of my program, this statement comes in middle of the program i.e; after taking some input commands then program comes to this point.

Let my program be stack_supporter.c . As an input it will take some options and perform some calculations and then comes to below point.

```
printf("Press any key to continue");
getchar();
calling_relevant_function();
```

I am using below batch file:

```
cd program_location_directory_path
./stack_supporter -o # -o is used to give options
```

and I am stuck in the middle of the program waiting for key press event. so how to automate these type of programs ?

Answer (score 1):

```
echo(|myProgram.exe
```

You can pipe something into the program standard input

Comment: Sorry If I am not clear before , editing the question

Comment: @user2499424, what is the source of your input options? the user, command line, a file, ... ?

Comment: I am just giving some default as of now from batch file itself (-d option) , my interest is to know whether we can bypass the getchar() function

Comment: @user2499424, If you are not getting data from the user, the pipe solution will force the `getchar` function to continue. If you need to get data from the user include another command line option to indicate batch usage and wrap the `getchar` in an if test.